# jQuery each loop for json data by index

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have some json data that the id number will change, so instead of referencing it by ID number I would like to reference it by array index.

I am looking to `alert` the source which would be the image URL `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/89/Chuck_Schumer_official_photo.jpg/240px-Chuck_Schumer_official_photo.jpg`

This is a sample of the json data:

```
{  
   "batchcomplete":"",
   "query":{  
      "normalized":[  
         {  
            "from":"Chuck_Schumer",
            "to":"Chuck Schumer"
         }
      ],
      "pages":{  
         "326708":{  
            "pageid":326708,
            "ns":0,
            "title":"Chuck Schumer",
            "thumbnail":{  
               "source":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/89/Chuck_Schumer_official_photo.jpg/240px-Chuck_Schumer_official_photo.jpg",
               "width":240,
               "height":300
            },
            "pageimage":"Chuck_Schumer_official_photo.jpg"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This is my JavaScript attempt:

```
function processWikiData(wikiData){
  $(wikiData.query).each(function(index, query_item) {
    $(query_item.pages).each(function(index, page_item) {
      // I was hoping to get the array's first index here but clearly this is wrong
      $(page_item.[0]).each(function(index, wiki_id) {
        $(wiki_id.thumbnail).each(function(index, thumbnail_item) {
          alert(thumbnail_item.source);
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Just use `Object.entries`, `Object.values`, `Object.keys`. No jQuery required and unrelated to JSON.

Comment: This question, if you want to call it that, is very unclear. Are you just trying to access `yourExampleObject.pages['326708'].thumbnail.source;`?

Comment: *"...instead of referencing it by ID number I would like to reference it by array index"* The data you want isn't in an array, and the "first" object property `"326708"` isn't necessarily guaranteed to be the same when fetching if there are more than one. But if there's always only one or you don't care which is first, then you can do this: `Object.values(data.query.pages)[0].thumbnail.source` *(assuming the JSON has been parsed, of course)*